# I can't edit the UITableView even if it is configured to be edited

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a UITableView in the iPad xib file.

The delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}
```

is correctly invoked.

But stil when I touch a row, or I swipe on it to delete it nothing happens.
In the xib file "User Interaction Enabled" for the table is on.

Thanks

UPDATE:
I've added this to the delegate, but still nothing:

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Comment: have you enabled the editing on tableview? it would be something like [self.myTable setEditing:YES]; I am sorry, I am away from my system so you have to check it yourself.

Comment: It is the same anwer of @Matthias. I actually don't want to enter in editing mode, I just want the table in the default mode and being able to swipe or select a row for deleting/editing

Comment: Actually, yes. My bad!
Have you tried if the control is transferred to this method when you swipe the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you implemented these methods :

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {   
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}
```

Comment: It is the same answer of @Karna

Comment: You have to implement both methods.Edited my answer.

Comment: One more thing, now swiping the row make the Delete button to appear. But how can I make the row editable when I touch it ? (without entering in the editing mode).

Comment: It is the wrong approach that you are trying to figure out.For UITableView selecting any row will call its delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath where you can turn editing on for your table but not for that single row and to display that delete button you have to perform swipe gesture.You are talking about something that Apple doesn't support.

Answer (score 0):

This method tells **if** the table **can** be edited.
To go into edit mode, call `[setEditing:YES animated:animated]`.

If you have setup a `editButtonItem`, it will do it for you when pressed.

Comment: But I actually don't want to be in edited mode, which is the method showing the red delete button for each row. I just want to display the default table view that it is responsive to touch gestures, such as swiping to delete a row, and selecting a row.